# Does googles xoauth standard support RSA-SHA1 based signatures?

Tags: oauth, cryptography, smtp, rsa

I have seen plenty examples where HMAC-SHA1 was used with xouath. An example on how to use RSA-SHA1 with xoauth would be a huge help.